# fill row with previous row from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe grouped by Client-Equipment, Date and Closing_Date. I show example:

| Customer- Equipment | Date | Closing Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05 |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-02 | NaN |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-03 | NaN |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-04 | NaN |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-05 | NaN |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-06 | NaN |
| Customer2 - Equipment H | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 |
| Customer2 - Equipment H | 2023-01-02 | NaN |
| Customer2 - Equipment H | 2023-01-03 | Nan |

I need to fill in the Closing dates until the date is equal to the closing date. The expected result would be:

| Customer- Equipment | Date | Closing Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-05 |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-05 |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-05 |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-05 |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-05 |
| Customer1 - Equipment A | 2023-01-06 | NaN |
| Customer2 - Equipment H | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 |
| Customer2 - Equipment H | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 |
| Customer2 - Equipment H | 2023-01-03 | Nan |

I'm trying codes like this:

```
df['test'] = df.groupby('Customer-Equipment').apply(
lambda x: x['Closing date'] if x['date'] <= x.at[row.index -1 ,'closing date'] else pd.NaT).fillna(method = 'ffill').reset_index(drop=True)
```

How could this be done in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are in increasing order, you could just [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Customer-Equipment')['Closing Date'].ffill()
df['Closing Date'] = s.where(s.ge(df['Date']))
```

Output:

```
        Customer-Equipment        Date Closing Date
0  Customer1 - Equipment A  2023-01-01   2023-01-05
1  Customer1 - Equipment A  2023-01-02   2023-01-05
2  Customer1 - Equipment A  2023-01-03   2023-01-05
3  Customer1 - Equipment A  2023-01-04   2023-01-05
4  Customer1 - Equipment A  2023-01-05   2023-01-05
5  Customer1 - Equipment A  2023-01-06          NaN
6  Customer2 - Equipment H  2023-01-01   2023-01-02
7  Customer2 - Equipment H  2023-01-02   2023-01-02
8  Customer2 - Equipment H  2023-01-03          Nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'Customer-Equipment': ['Customer1 - Equipment A'] * 6 + ['Customer2 - Equipment H'] * 3,
    'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-06',
                            '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03']),
    'Closing Date': [pd.to_datetime('2023-01-05')] * 5 + [pd.to_datetime('2023-01-02'), pd.NaT, pd.NaT]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def fill_closing_dates(group):
    closing_date = group['Closing Date'].iloc[0]
    group['Closing Date'] = group['Date'].apply(lambda x: closing_date if x <= closing_date else pd.NaT)
    return group

df = df.groupby('Customer-Equipment').apply(fill_closing_dates)

print(df)
```